# caracteres esquisitos ao imprimir na textarea

Tags: javascript

não estou conseguindo imprimir corretamente os caracteres.
se eu escrever qualquer coisa dentro da html, os caracteres ficam normais.
 `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

- se eu escrever um texto com caracteres especiais no javascript e mandar printar em uma textarea: **"Indicação"**, isso acaba retornando na textarea `IndicaÃ§Ã£o`

  ```
  document.getElementById('textarea').value = "Indicação";
  ```

tem algum modo de printar isso certo?
o único modo de printar "certo" é fazendo o que o rapaz deste blog falou?
http://marcelomaidden.blogspot.com.br/2012/11/como-colocar-acentuacao-em-alerts.html

Comment: O Javascript está em um arquivo externo?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/teste.js" charset="ISO-8859-1"></script>` sim. tentei fazer algo do tipo, mas não deu.

Comment: @João na tag Meta você colocou UTF-8, e no exemplo do javascript colocou ISO-8859-1, não conheço muito de charsets, mas não deveria ser o mesmo?

Comment: não deu certo se eu colocar os mesmos valores.

Comment: Veja se o arquivo JavaScript está codificado como ISO-8859-1. Isso já aconteceu comigo, os scripts PHP ficavam com os acentos quebrados pois o HTML estava em UTF-8 e os scripts em ISO-8859-1 (mesmo com o header do mesmo apontando UTF-8). Para converter os arquivos você pode usar o Notepad++ ou qualquer outro editor de texto. No Notepad++: Menu > Encoding > `Enconde in UTF-8 without BOM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

João, o problema é que os charsets dos seus arquivos estão incompatíveis.

Não sei o editor que você está usando, mas para evitar problemas, você deve salvar todos os arquivos com o mesmo charset, de preferência UTF-8.

E para garantir a compatibilidade com o browser, eu ainda costumo utilizar a tag `<meta charset="utf-8" />` logo após `<head>` no meu arquivo html.

Você pode usar o Notepad++ [http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download] para conferir o charset dos seus arquivos e até mesmo converter. (menu "Formatar").

Answer (score -2):

no meu caso as soluções não estavam resolvendo esse problema.
Tinha faltado configurar o idioma no arquivo html(tag html lang="pt-br").

Isso resolveu o problema.